# greasemonkey help (replace html tags)

Tags: html, greasemonkey

I am new to greasemonkey and would like to learn to use it to remove javascript enforcers. Like this one

```
<span class="lazyload" style="display:block; width:100%;height:100%;" data-imgSrc="//img4.leboncoin.fr/ad-thumb/whatsoever.jpg" data-imgAlt="nevermind"></span>
```

that should read

```
<img style="width:100%; height:100%;" src="http://img4.leboncoin.fr/ad-thumb/whatsoever.jpg" data-imgAlt="nevermind">
```

In principle this can be done by some search&replaces. In sed-speak

```
's|span class="lazyload" style="display:block;|img style="|gi'
's|data-imgSrc="//|src="http://|gi'
```

does the job.

As pointed out a lot, (here for example [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)), 
such replacements may be bad. But when applied to a specific page they are quick ...

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about regexps when dealing with live web pages because replacing HTML directly will break event listeners (click handlers etc.) attached in js code via addEventListener or `.on` properties.

Here's an excerpt from the code I'm using.

```js
delazify();

// also delazify new dynamically added content
new MutationObserver(delazify).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});

function delazify() {
    var lazies = document.getElementsByClassName('lazyload');
    for (var i = lazies.length; --i >= 0; ) {
        var el = lazies[i];
        var src = el.getAttribute('data-imgSrc');
        if (src) {
            el.src = src;
            el.removeAttribute('data-imgSrc');
            el.classList.remove('lazyload');
        }
    }
}
```

It's really simple, the only noteworthy thing is that in MutationObserver callback instead of looping through mutation records and added nodes, which may be slow in case of lots of nodes, I directly iterate by class name because `getElementsByClassName` is extremely fast.